# Exe media file conversion to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, exe, mp4

I have an exe file which is actually a media file which I need to convert to mp4. It contains footage from CCTV cameras.When I open that exe file,a launcher called SecureView is opened and the video can be played inside that player.
I need to convert that exe to mp4 for viewing it in other normal media players.
I have used a tool called exe2swf but there was no swf file in it.
Is there any way to separate that launcher from the video?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file with a ZIP program, like 7-zip.

Comment: It cant be opened like that.

Comment: Sometimes it works (self-extracting archives are an example), you're out of luck then I'm afraid.

Comment: Its not an archive.

Comment: (I hope you tried my previous suggestion, at least...) Use `ffmpeg` to see if there is any video stream information available, the command would be `ffmpeg -i mymovie.exe`. Obviously you run this from a command prompt started in same folder as both your movie file and `ffmpeg.exe` (`shift+right click` to have the command prompt option in your context menu)

Comment: I have tried your previous suggestion and I have tried ffmpeg long before and it is giving error as invalid data.

Comment: I dont think you have understood my problem.I want to separate the launcher from the video so that the application wont open automatically when I open exe file.

Comment: Alright, your luck is really running out here. Have you tried something like exe explorer? If that doesn't give any results, I'm afraid you will have to record the whole video with a lossless screen capture. You don't happen to be able to give a sample file would you?

Comment: Exe explorer dont work.I cant upload since it is nearly 200mb.Anyways thanks.